# mysql negation from multiple entires

Tags: mysql, join, query-performance, subquery

i have one customer_products table with have the mapping of customer to products it is using

```
customer_id   product_id
c1           p1
c1           p2
c1           p3
c2           p1
c2           p2
c3           p1
```

I want to get all the customers that are using p2 but not p3. Is it possible to achieve this without using nested queries

i was able to solve the problem with join of nested queries. But as nested joins are too slow i am not able to get desired performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A query using conditional aggregation in the having clause to select all customers that have purchased product_id p2 at least once and have never purchased product_id p3

```
select customer_id
from mytable
where product_id in ('p2','p3')
group by customer_id
having count(case when product_id = 'p2' then 1 end) > 0
and count(case when product_id = 'p3' then 1 end) = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible, using an anti-join pattern.  That's a left join, to return all customers using `p2`, along with matching rows (same `customer_id`) but using `p3`, and then filter out all the rows that had a match, with a predicate in the WHERE clause.

For example:

```
SELECT cp2.customer_id
  FROM customer_products cp2
  LEFT
  JOIN customer_products cp3
    ON cp3.customer_id = cp2.customer_id
   AND cp3.product_id = 'p3' 
 WHERE cp2.product_id = 'p2'
   AND cp3.product_id IS NULL
```

Add the `DISTINCT` keyword a `GROUP BY cp2.customer_id` clause to eliminate duplicates (if `(customer_id,product_id)` is not guaranteed to be unique.)

Appropriate indexes will improve performance for large sets.